# Exponential notation in attribute table QGIS

Tags: qgis

I've imported a spreadsheet from excel, all my spreadsheet data is formated as "number" inside it. 
When I import it in QGIS, it changes to exponential notation as shown in the image below. Is there a way to change this?

[image]

Comment: I can't answer the question but a temporary work-around could be to make a new field and populate it using the ROUND() function.

Comment: why is this a problem? the actual value is the same.

Comment: @IanTurton for presentation, in a legend for people who don't have a scientific knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the "Precision" in the legend format section of the graduated styling settings. In your case as these are tiny numbers you'll need at least 9 or 10 there but it will go upto 15.

[image]